# Does the VMware virtual machine use hardware and other resources of the host system?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Does the VMware virtual machine use hardware and other resources of the host system? I read that it creates it virtually, but I am not able to understand what it means to create it virtually.

Comment: If it didn't use at least some hardware of its host, how could it run?

Comment: I think the crux is "what does it mean to 'use' the hardware"? Clearly it does to some extent, but the VM also doesn't have direct access or even know what the hardware is, so it also doesn't, to an extent.

Comment: @Brobdingnagian Who said the access had to be direct?

Comment: @Mooing Duck If it doesn't have direct access, how does it access the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Take the LAN connection for example. Your virtual machine most likely doesn't have access to its own separate Ethernet card that gives it access to the internet. Yet it still has access to the internet. How could that be?

Under the hood, the virtualization software is creating a fake, "virtual" ethernet card that it presents to the guest OS. When the guest OS asks "What PCI devices do I have?" to what it thinks is the hardware, the VM software answers by saying "You have these: ...", and listing the fake Ethernet card, among others.

Whenever the guest OS tries to read/write to this Ethernet device, the VM software will intercept those calls, and do what is necessary to make them function. In the Ethernet case, that means that the VM software will broker the communication between the virtualized Ethernet card (that it presents to the guest OS), and the native networking facilities offered by the host OS (which in-turn communicate with the real, hardware Ethernet card on your machine).

This same process is done for all kinds of virtual devices:

1. Virtual mice/keyboards (whose commands come from your interaction with the VM window)
2. Virtual graphics cards/display outputs (whose contents are drawn to the VM window)
3. Virtual power management systems (which let the VM software close the VM window when it detects the guest OS has performed a shutdown)
4. Virtual sound cards (which mix the output audio into the output of the host computer, just like it were any other app's output)
5. etc.

Alternatively, some devices can be "passed through". This allows the guest OS to access a physical device directly, with minimal VM intervention.

For example, suppose your host OS lacks driver support for a particular USB device. Because your host OS doesn't know how to use the device, the VM software can't rely on the OS to manage the interaction with the device. But there's a clever workaround: instead, the VM software could pass along the hardware USB device to the guest OS. Whatever USB signalling instructions the guest OS tries to make, it'll opaquely communicate back and forth to the USB hardware. This allows the guest OS to use its own driver to interact with the otherwise host-unsupported hardware.